# React - Reset State stored from axios fetch

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch, axios

I am trying to reset the state for an object stored in my `users` array on click with `handleDelete` after I remove from the database. However, my state is not changing. I am able to log the current user with `console.log('found: ' + this.state.users[i])`. Basically, I have a table populated from my API and am trying to remove the row for the state without refreshing the page, but the state is not updating.

The constructor where my initial state is stored:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  };
```

Grabbing the API on mount:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/myAPI')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
  }
```

Mapping over data stored in state from fetch

```
  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {this.state.users.map(user =>
          <tr key={user.uniqueid}>
            <td>{user.name}</td>
            <td>{user.versions}</td>
            <td>{user.type}</td>
            <td>{user.hours}</td>
            <td>{user.refresh}</td>
            <td>{user.uniqueid}</td>
            <td>{user.date}</td>
            <td><Button onClick={this.handleDelete} data-id={user.uniqueid}><FaTrashO /></Button></td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
```

delete handler where I am TRYING to reset state for :

```
  handleDelete(e) {
    let dataId = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');

    axios({
      method: 'delete',
      responseType: 'json',
      url: '/myAPI',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT"
      },
      data: { _id: dataId }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(dataId + ' deleted with axios')

      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.users.length; i++){
        if (dataId === this.state.users[i]._id) {

          let currentObj = this.state.users[i];
          console.log('found: ' + this.state.users[i])

          this.setState((prevState) => {
            currentObj._id = ''
            currentObj.date = '',
            currentObj.hours = '',
            currentObj.name = '',
            currentObj.refresh = '',
            currentObj.type = '',
            currentObj.uniqueid = '',
            currentObj.versions = ''
          });
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    })
  }
```

Example of what im calling from my API:

```
[
{
_id: "XJAbmHCX",
name: "an_example_2",
type: "B",
versions: "10",
hours: "10",
refresh: "Yes",
uniqueid: "XJAbmHCX",
date: "2018/01/08",
__v: 0
},
{
_id: "TOoIi7xS",
name: "test",
type: "A",
versions: "10",
hours: "10",
refresh: "Yes",
uniqueid: "TOoIi7xS",
date: "2018/01/09",
__v: 0
},
{
_id: "oeaigjesroigj",
name: "an_example_2_1",
type: "B",
versions: "10",
hours: "10",
refresh: "Yes",
uniqueid: "oeaigjesroigj",
date: "2018/01/08",
__v: 0
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop of `handleDelete`, I simply sliced the user adn returned every object without the current ID to the state

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.users.length; i++){
        if (dataId === this.state.users[i]._id) {
          let users = this.state.users.slice();
          users = users.filter(u => { return u._id !== dataId; });
          this.setState({ users: users });

        }
      }
```